# Passing a substring to a function or sub

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I'm trying to send each character of a string object to a subroutine. I'm using the following code to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
string sInput = "some text"
for (int i=1; i < sInput.length(); i++) {
  showLetter(sInput.substring(i, i));
}
```

Subroutine:

```
void showLetter(String sInput)
```

My belief is that this should be iterating through the string and selecting one character (not to be confused with a char) at a time and sending it to the subroutine.

I haven't used C++ for 30 years and I am having difficulty finding why this won't work. I understand that I could use a char array, but I wanted to use this method.

If C++/Arduino coding doesn't work this way, to get credit you MUST explain why not.

Any help would be appreciated.

entire code follows...

```
/*
visual morse code

a dot is 1 unit
a dash is 3 units
  space between parts of the same letter is one unit
the space between letters is 3 units
the space between words is 7 units
*/

void parseString(String sInput);
void showletter(char sInput);
void dot(void); //dot
void dash(void);  //dash
void letterSeparator(void); //between letters
void wordSeparator(void); //space
int baseUnitLength = 100;

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup(){
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop(){
  //call a routine with a string.  
  //the routine parses the string and blinks the dot and dash for morse code for each character

  parseString("sos ");


  //showLetter("s");
  //showLetter("o");
  //showLetter("s");
  //showLetter(" ");
}

void parseString(String sInput)
{
  for (int i=1; i<sInput.length(); i++){
    showLetter(sInput.substring(i,i));
  }
}
void showLetter(String sInput){
  if (sInput == "a")
    {
      dot();
      dash();
      letterSeparator();
    }
  else if (sInput == "b")
    {
      dash();
      dot();
      dot();
      dot();
      letterSeparator();
    }
  else if (sInput == "s")
    {
      dot();
      dot();
      dot();
      letterSeparator();
    }
  else if (sInput == "o")
    {
      dash();
      dash();
      dash();
      letterSeparator();
    }
  else if (sInput == " ")
    {
      wordSeparator();
    }
}
void dot(){
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   
    delay(baseUnitLength);                       
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
    delay(baseUnitLength);                       
  }
void dash(){
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   
    delay(baseUnitLength * 3);                       
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
    delay(baseUnitLength);                       
  }
void letterSeparator(){
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
    delay(baseUnitLength * 3);                       
  }
void wordSeparator(){
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
    delay(baseUnitLength * 6);                       
  }
```

Comment: If you write "to get credit you MUST explain...", then it is likely you won't get any response. People here are not answering for credits, they answer because they want to help.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't exactly helpful either...

Comment: If you haven't been working with C++ for 30 years, then you are totally outdated with the language as it stands today. I'd suggest you update your knowledge first. Also, regarding your question, if you had taken a look at `String` API in Arduino reference, then you would have found out what are the problems with your code.

Comment: @dda - i'm sorry if my description of the result is unacceptable.  I quite frankly do not what else to say.  The issue is clearly in the for loop in the code.  When executed it does nothing. No blinking, Nothing. I assumed people who have worked with and know arduino/C++ would either know why this doesn't work or would attempt to recreate a situation where it does.  Sorry, but that's all I have.

Comment: So here is the answer you did not find in the Arduino reference https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringSubstring for 2nd argument: **to (optional): the index to end the substring before** Note the "before" mention, which mean `substring(i,i)` will always be empty as it should be `substring(i,i+1)`. And this is actually NOT a C++ question, but only an Arduino API question.

Comment: @jfpoilpret I thank you very much for your help. The arduino example i read, references 5 characters, but the substring method/function returns 4.  i don't understand why I have to +1 the second parameter and it isn't clearly stated that this is what you have to do nor why you have to do it.  the documentation clearly states, "with two parameters looks for a given substring from the first parameter to the second." That's not very clear, to me, in regards to positional reference and not how other languages do it.

Comment: It is very common. This is called a "semi-open" range, which is how the STL (Standard Template Library) also does it. See, for example, [a Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19421642). Without a semi-open range it is impossible to pass an empty range. The documentation for `substring` is very clear on this point: *the optional ending index is exclusive (the corresponding character is not included in the substring).*

Answer (score 1):

Mr. jfpoilpret provided me with the answer and should be credited, as such.
It appears the subString function needs to have 1 added to the second parameter in order to properly reference the number of characters you need in the String.
In my case, iterating through a String and referencing only one character at a time means I need to do the following sInput.substring(i,i+1)
Also, the String object uses a zero based index.
EX:
   String sString = "This is a peach.";
   sString.substring(0,4)     //should return "This"
   sString.substring(8,9)     //should return "a"
   sString.substring(15,16)   //should return "."

In addition, you could also use the String function charAt (EX: sString.charAt(i)).
The charAt returns a char and if you are passing it to a function/sub you need to make sure the function/sub is expecting a char data type.
Also, it is easier to use a switch case when using the charAt function, as you don't have to do a conversion from String to char, as switch case does not work with Strings.

Comment: I understand you are trying to learn stuff, but what you are doing is highly inefficient. On a microcontroller memory is short, and the String library in particular tends to fragment memory. Your technique of breaking up a String into individual single-character String objects is the very thing that is likely to fragment memory. You are much better off converting it to an array (using [c_str](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CStr)) and then indexing into that in the usual C way.

Answer (score 1):

You got your answer, and you understood how this works. However, your
sentence “*It appears the subString function needs to have 1 added to
the second parameter [...]*” makes me believe you find this behavior
somewhat contrived, whereas it should be intuitive to any C or C++
programmer.

As I think this may help, I will share here the mental picture I use for
thinking about array indices. I call it the “L-shaped cursor”, and it
goes like this:

An array index can represent two different things:

- a particular cell within the array
- an “edge” of a cell, i.e. either the limit between two cells or an
  edge of the whole array.

This is depicted in following picture of an array of length `N`, where
the numbers above it are the edge indices and the numbers below are the
cell indices. `i` and `j` are just two particular indices:

```
0   1   2           i           j               N
┌───┬───┬───┬───────┰───┬───────┰───┬───────┬───┐
│   │   │   │  ⋅⋅⋅  ┃   │  ⋅⋅⋅  ┃   │  ⋅⋅⋅  │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───────┺━━━┵───────┺━━━┵───────┴───┘
  0   1   2           i           j          N−1
```

Since each index can represent two things, I like to think about them as
being L-shaped cursors, like the ones I've drawn in bold for the indices
`i` and `j`.

Now, if you think about the purpose of the `substring()` method, it's
job is to cut a slice along the string, and you need to tell it where to
place the “knife”. Since the knife will cut along edges, it's perfectly
natural to use edge indices for that. Then

```
someString.substring(i, j)
```

will give you the slice of the string that lies between the edges `i`
and `j`. Looking at the picture above you can see this includes the cell
numbered `i` but not the one numbered `j`.

I hope this picture helps you find the behavior of `substring()` more
natural now. It *does* help me avoid [fencepost
errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).

Comment: Very nice and I thank you for the information.  you hit the nail on the head in your first paragraph.  I'm used to higher level OO languages and scripting code where this is never an issue. So to me, it appears somewhat odd. But, it makes sense once it was explained.  I took C++ forever ago because it was required but I haven't touched it since.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggestion the following:

```
String sInput = "some text";

void showLetter(char c);

for (int i = 1; i < sInput.length(); i++) {
  showLetter(sInput[i]);
}
```

Rewritten using C/C++ strings (null-terminated character vector):

```
const char* sInput = "some text";

void showLetter(char c);

for (int i = 1; i < strlen(sInput); i++) {
  showLetter(sInput[i]);
}
```

And slightly more efficient:

```
const char* sInput = "some text";

void showLetter(char c);

const char* sp = sInput;
char c;
while ((c = *sp++) != 0) {
  showLetter(c);
}
```

The next step is to move the string literal to program memory to reduce the amount of RAM needed.

Cheers!

Comment: Mikael - thank you for the attempt, but I understand chars and char arrays and how to pass by value and reference.  However, what I'm looking for is an answer to why, what I am trying to do, doesn't work.  To me the substring function appears to return a string object that I should be able to pass to a function/sub expecting a string as an argument.  But, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "But, it doesn't seem to be working". Is that a compile or run-time error? Are the parameters to substring() correct?

Comment: no errors. the application compiles and loads into the arduino Uno, but produces no output.  I guess I could have been clearer on that point.